# Calling C function from Python

Tags: python, c

I made use of a server file which was written in Python to build connection between my Raspberry Pi and my iPhone. And i wrote a simple C program that help translate morse-code. I want to call the `translate()` function in the C program from the Python server program.

I found a tutorial online and followed its instructions to write my C program and edit the `netio_server.py` file

In my C program `morseCodeTrans.c` it's like

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static PyObject* py_translate(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
char *letter;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &letter);

if(strcmp(letter, ".-") == 0)
  return Py_BuildValue("c", 'A');
else if(strcmp(letter, "-...") == 0)
  return Py_BuildValue("c", 'B');
...

}

static PyMethodDef morseCodeTrans_methods[] = {
  {"translate", py_translate, METH_VARARGS},
  {NULL, NULL} 
};

void initmorseCodeTrans()
{
  (void)Py_InitModule("morseCodeTrans", morseCodeTrans_methods);
}
```

And in the server file netio_server.py it's like:

```
# other imports
import morseCodeTrans

...

tempLetter = ''

if line == 'short':
  tempLetter += '.'
elif line == 'long':
  tempLetter += '-' 
elif line == 'shortPause': 
  l = morseCodeTrans.translate(tempLetter)
  print "The letter is", l
```

Above is the only place that I would call the C `translate()` function

Then I tried to compile `morseCodeTrans.c` file like this:

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -o myModule.so myModule.c
```

The compile was successful. 
But when I ran the Python server program, whenever it reached the line

```
l = morseCodeTrans.translate(tempLetter)
```

The server program just terminated without any error message.

I'm very new to Python programming, so I couldn't figure out where the problem is. Any help?

Comment: You might have an easier time with the `ctypes` module (look at the documentation from the standard library).

Comment: Yeah, i know ctypes is easier to use. But right now i don't have enough time to go through the tutorial, maybe later i'll try to use ctypes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just got some minor mixups in the interface. I modified the code as follows to make it work:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static PyObject* py_translate(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
  char *letter;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &letter);

  if(strcmp(letter, ".-") == 0)
    return Py_BuildValue("c", 'A');
  else if(strcmp(letter, "-...") == 0)
    return Py_BuildValue("c", 'B');
  /* ... */
  else
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef morseCodeTrans_methods[] = {
  {"translate", py_translate, METH_VARARGS, ""},
  {0} 
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initmorseCodeTrans(void)
{
  Py_InitModule("morseCodeTrans", morseCodeTrans_methods);
}
```

It's much safer to build with `distutils`, since it prevents you from accidentally linking against wrong versions of Python. Use the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
module = Extension('morseCodeTrans', sources=['morseCodeTrans.c'])
setup(ext_modules=[module])
```

Simply use as `python setup.py install`.

**Edit**

Despite the mixups in the interface, it appears your code still works. Then your problem is most likely during linking. As mentioned above, using `distutils` should remedy this. If you absolutely want to build manually, use `python-config --cflags`, `python-config --ldflags` etc. to make sure you link against the correct version of Python.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your reply. I've tried to write the setup.py file and do python setup.py install, but there's an error message said "TypeError: _init_() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)" and that was referred to this line "module = Extension('morseCodeTrans', source=['morseCodeTrans.c'])"

Comment: Never mind, i just added another parameter to Extension(): 
Extension(morseCodeTrans, library_dirs=['/usr/local/include'], sources=['morseCodeTrans.c']) and problem solved. Thanks again, now my program works perfectly fine ^ ^

Comment: Good that it works now! The `TypeError` was due to your typo: `sources -> source`. No need to add another parameter to `Extension()`.